# HikariCP Postgresql Driver Claims to not accept JDBC URL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, cloud-foundry, hikaricp

I've pushed my application to cloudfoundry. However every time I connect to my postgresql/elephant sql I received this error

```
 Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept JDBC URL jdbc:postgres://cwkqmdql:SsVqwdLxQObgaJAYu68O-8gTY1VmS9LX@pellefant.db.elephantsql.com:5432/cwkqmdql/
```

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: The URL is indeed invalid. If the part `cwkqmdql:SsVqwdLxQObgaJAYu68O-8gTY1VmS9LX` is supposed to be username and password, then you can't specify it like that. See the manual for the correct URL: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried changing my spring.datasource.url to this jdbc:postgres://pellefant-01.db.elephantsql.com:5432/cwkqmdql and the same error still persists

Answer (score 98):

There are a few issues with that URL and a latest PSQL driver may complain.

1. `jdbc:postgres:` should be replaced with `jdbc:postgresql:`
2. Do not use `jdbc:postgresql://<username>:<passwor>...`, user parameters instead: `jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>`
3. In some cases you have to force SSL connection by adding `sslmode=require` parameter

So your URL should be:

`jdbc:postgresql://@pellefant.db.elephantsql.com:5432/cwkqmdql?user=cwkqmdql&password=SsVqwdLxQObgaJAYu68O-8gTY1VmS9LX`

or

`jdbc:postgresql://@pellefant.db.elephantsql.com:5432/cwkqmdql?user=cwkqmdql&password=SsVqwdLxQObgaJAYu68O-8gTY1VmS9LX&sslmode=require`

I hope that will help.

Comment: In my case, I needed a trailing forward slash. Like `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/`

Comment: didn´t work for me with Spring Boot 2 on Heroku Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, it was caused by jdbc:postgre:/ I replaced it by jdbc:postgresql:/ and it's ok

Comment: why @ is added along with host name? In my case it worked when I removed '@' from host name.

Comment: This answer relly helped with me connecting to Heroku Postgres from local machine

Comment: Why not using that in (2.)... but use parameters instead?

Comment: sslmode=require did it for me, thanks

Answer (score 25):

In my case it was defining the property in double quotes in the java.properties file

by changing

```
jdbcUrl="url"
```

to

```
jdbcUrl=url
```

it works again

Comment: ooops, that was my issue, too. Thank you

Comment: This was the issue too. For my case, the confusion comes from different syntax for different config files (application.properties vs application.yml)

Comment: what if i am using helm chart to create secret and while creating secrets we need to surround each value with quotes.. then in applications.properties, we inject the env var.

Comment: First make sure you have imported the driver in pom.xml (in case you're using maven), then proceed to read the answers

Answer (score 12):

The issue I had was that I had given double quotes for the datasource url in the properties file.

***What I had given*** :

```
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
```

***The correct way to give the url is*** :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

also had this error, but realized it was because i had typed
`postgressql`
instead of
`postgresql` in my url

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error until I realize that I did not set my profile to active in the application.properties class.

```
spring.profiles.active = dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
postgresql://localhost/db_name
```

with

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with h2 DB in WebFlux. The issue was with `spring.datasource.driver`

Not working

```
spring.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver
```

Working

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
I had previously used the following in my application.properties. I had prefixed the database url with jdbc:postgres

```
    >JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgres://host.com:5432/dbName
```

We need to use **postgresql** instead of postgres.

```
    >JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.com:5432/dbName
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, two configuration files are in different format:

1. `application.properties` in `src/main/resources`
2. `application.yml` in `src/test/resources`

After changing `application.yml` to `application.properties` in `src/test/resources`, the issue was fixed.