# Spring Boot Hikari wrong connection url

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm making a web app using spring boot but I don't wanna set connection url, username and password in `application.properties` so I config DataSource programmatically via HikariCP.

Here is my code:

DBConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        DataSource ds = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl(System.getenv("WJ_URL"));
            config.setUsername(System.getenv("WJ_USER"));
            config.setPassword(System.getenv("WJ_PASS"));
            config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");

            ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        }

        return ds;

    }

}
```

I pretty sure that I set correct URL and another credentials info but it still got exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Here is the connection url via system env:

`WJ_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db.sakadream.me:5432/weebjournal`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213381/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-for-postgresql/50213758#50213758

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741443/hikaricp-postgresql-driver-claims-to-not-accept-jdbc-url

Comment: Did you modify the environment variable after application is started?

Comment: @LHCHIN Absolutely no. I even double-checked

Comment: You have to do provide connections for HIKARICP as well as SPRING.DATASOURCE . I was facing the same thing