# Spring cloud dataflow with Postgresq

Tags: postgresql-9.3, spring-cloud-dataflow

I installed scdf and I can access it correctly via the url and the shell. The problem that once I reboot the system I lose everything I did (saw the use of the base H2). When I try to use Postgresql as follows:

```
 java -Dloader.path=lib -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar \
  --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432 / test \
  --spring.datasource.username=postgres \
  --spring.datasource.password=root \
  --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver &. I have the following error: 
 [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context 
 initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' 
 defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
 [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, 
 jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
 2019-11-20 13:38:54.610  INFO 29707 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   
 : Stopping service [Tomcat]
 2019-11-20 13:38:54.640 ERROR 29707 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               
 : Application run failed

 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' 
 defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
 [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, 
 jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at  org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.single.DataFlowServerApplication.main(DataFlowServerApplication.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, 
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:108)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at  org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d16b7abf.getConnection(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356)
        at  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$LocationResolver.getDatabaseDriver(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$LocationResolver.resolveLocations(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:378)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$LocationResolver.resolveLocations(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.configureProperties(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:192)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:150)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bc90f93.CGLIB$flyway$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bc90f93$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$61f0455.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1bc90f93.flyway(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Can you help me please!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried as you recommanded it ' java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar \ --spring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataflow" \ --spring.datasource.username=postgres \ --spring.datasource.password=root \ --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver'

Answer (score 2):

It seems the root-cause points to:

> Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432

I notice an obvious thing in your value portion of it. There appears to be a "space" before and after the database schema [ee: `/ test`]. You may want to try it as:

```
 java -Dloader.path=lib -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar \
  --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test \
  --spring.datasource.username=postgres \
  --spring.datasource.password=root \
  --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Other than that, there isn't anything I see as wrong in your properties, but I see some folks having success quoting the value in double-quotes [see: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741443/hikaricp-postgresql-driver-claims-to-not-accept-jdbc-url)].

Perhaps you could also try:

> --spring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Sabby, I treid with '--spring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" ' I haven't any error but it continues to use H2 and and it does not take into account the parameters of postgresql

Comment: you can see the details of the server response in my answer. Sorry I can not post it in commant since it's long.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I tried as you recommanded it ' java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar \ --spring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataflow" \ --spring.datasource.username=postgres \ --spring.datasource.password=root \ --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver' . I haven't any error but it continues to use H2. You can see it in this code '2019-11-21 11:22:09.846  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
2019-11-21 11:22:09.872  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:19092/mem:dataflow (H2 1.4)
2019-11-21 11:22:09.927  WARN 10379 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.base.Database    : Flyway upgrade recommended: H2 1.4.199 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
2019-11-21 11:22:10.032  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.053s)
2019-11-21 11:22:10.051  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history_dataflow"
2019-11-21 11:22:10.083  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2019-11-21 11:22:10.086  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - INITIAL SETUP
2019-11-21 11:22:10.152  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.106s)
2019-11-21 11:22:10.409  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2019-11-21 11:22:10.525  INFO 10379 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-11-21 11:22:10.529  INFO 10379 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-11-21 11:22:10.844  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-11-21 11:22:11.583  INFO 10379 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-11-21 11:22:12.838  INFO 10379 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-11-21 11:22:13.926  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-21 11:22:14.017  WARN 10379 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-11-21 11:22:14.981  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : ** No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2 **
2019-11-21 11:22:15.037  INFO 10379 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.b.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean  :** No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2 **
2019-11-21 11:22:15.620  INFO 10379 --- [           main] .s.c.DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration : Skipper URI [http://localhost:7577/api]
2019-11-21 11:22:15.929'