# Postgresql Driver does not accept heroku postgres database url

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, heroku-postgres

I configured the database in application.properties with the spring.datasource.url property, using the DATABASE_URL that I see when running
`heroku config`
from terminal

I get "Postgresql Driver Claims to not accept JDBC URL" error when running the app from IntelliJ.

Tried solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741443/hikaricp-postgresql-driver-claims-to-not-accept-jdbc-url)post, but none of them helped.

Comment: Having a reference is nice, but you still need to tell us specifically what *you* did, and what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

I am deployiong on Heroku Postgres.
I found a working solution in [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url).

The correct jdbc url can be accessed through the heroku cli in your terminal:

```
heroku run echo \$JDBC_DATABASE_URL
```

I put the url into src/main/resources/application.properties like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=<your jdbc url>
```